# how can i auto resume the video after going to another app?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have 2 questions
I am trying to make a video intro for my app which will be like that:
the user will open the app the video will play then he will go to the main screen
my question if if the user opens another app or went to the home screen and then he open the app the video will disappear how can i make it resume from the point it were stopped?

my second question is how to make the video plays on portrait and orientation mode without making the video rest
my code:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var inte= Intent(this,Main_menu::class.java)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
        va.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        val videoview : VideoView = va
        val uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + R.raw.intro)
        videoview.setVideoURI(uri)
        va.setZOrderOnTop(true)
        videoview.start()


        Handler().postDelayed({

    startActivity(inte)},7000)
}
```

Comment: you just need to save the current state and on Resume just start from that state.

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `onResume()` and inside it write the code to continue playing the video

There is a thing called "activity lifecycle", that whenever state of your activity/app changes (or is about to change), each related method is called, which can be overridden by you to do what ever you want at that point, in this case it would be `onResume()` since you want the video to continue after coming back to app hence the "resume", you can easily override it by Control + O then search it in there

Here is a good explanation of [Activity LifeCycles](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) from Android developer website, there're charts and everything you can use to figure out how each state is placed